# Selecting random scores from a .txt file and finding their average (Python)

Tags: python, random

I've been trying to select scores at random from a .txt file and then finding the average of these randomly selected scores. Below is an example:

```
James, 0.974
Harry, 0.971
Ben, 0.968
Tom, 0.965
George, 0.964
```

For the sake of simplicity, I'd just like to select 2 scores at random to start with. See below:

```
James, 0.974
Harry, 0.971 <---
Ben, 0.968
Tom, 0.965 <---
George, 0.964
```

The end result would then be (Harry and Tom):

Average = 0.968

Can anyone help? I've been using 'split', 'import random' etc. But I'm not great at putting these all together. This is embarrassing, but here's what I've got so far...

```
import random

stroke = random.choice(open('stroke.txt').readlines()) 
for x in stroke:
    name, score = stroke.split(',')
    score = int(score)
    stroke.append((name, score))
print(stroke)
```

Comment: using `split`, `import random` etc. are great starts, can you share the code you've started so we can know where you're stuck? if so, please click the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/46354573/edit) button under the question and add your code as text (select, then format your code with the `{}` button), thanks.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, I've done what you asked. I hope it helps (I'm sure it won't sorry!)

Comment: Code is a very good start indeed. Can you explain what output you are getting , including any errors , and tell how that differs from what you want / expect ?

Answer (score 3):

Try with this (explanation on the code):

```
import random

# read the file in lines
with open('file.txt','r') as f:
    lines = f.read().splitlines()

# split in ',' and get the scores as float numbers 
scores = [ float(i.split(',')[1]) for i in lines]

# get two random numbers
rs = random.sample(scores, 2)

# compute the average
avg = sum(rs)/len(rs)
print avg
```

Now if you wanted to modify your code you could do it like this:

```
import random

# pick two instead of one
stroke = random.sample(open('file.txt').readlines(),2) 

scores = []
for x in stroke:
    # split item of list not the list itself
    name, score = x.split(',')
    # store the two scores on the scores list
    scores.append(float(score))

print (scores[0]+scores[1])/2
```

As @MadPhysicist proposed in the comments, instead of doing `(scores[0]+scores[1])/2` a more general way would be `sum(scores)/len(scores)` since this would work even for more than just two scores.

Comment: `list(f)` is a more idiomatic form of `f.read().splitlines()`

Comment: @MadPhysicist They are both doing the same thing in this case, my opinion is that `list(f)` is a bit more general expression.

Comment: You probably want + instead of / in the second version in the average.

Comment: `sum(scores)/len(scores)` would be more general. OP mentions that 2 is just an example.

Comment: @MadPhysicist yep, thanks! didn't even notice that one :)

Comment: @MadPhysicist yes good point! I'll update, `sum` is much more elegant to use instead!

Comment: Cheers, guys. Thanks so much!

Comment: There's no need for the calls to `rstrip` here: the `float` constructor accepts strings with leading and/or trailing whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the `scores.txt` file is formatted like so:

```
James, 0.974
Harry, 0.971
Ben, 0.968
Tom, 0.965
George, 0.964
```

Then this should do the trick:

```
import random

scores = open('scores.txt','r').read()
scores = scores.split('\n')

for i in range(len(scores)):
    scores[i] = scores[i].split(', ')
    scores[i][1] = float(scores[i][1]) * 1000

def rand_avg_scores(scorelist):
    score1 = scorelist.pop(random.randint(0,len(scorelist)-1))
    score2 = scorelist.pop(random.randint(0,len(scorelist)-1))

    finalscore = (score1[1] + score2[1])/2000

    return score1[0], score2[0], finalscore

print(rand_avg_scores(scores))
```

I added the `* 1000` and `/2000` bit to account for floating point errors. If the scores have more significant digits, add more zeroes accordingly.

Comment: This hard codes 2 scores. Op specifically mentions that 2 is an example, i.e., should not be hard coded.

Comment: The 1000, 2000 bit does not work the way you imagine, especially given the ~15 decimal places that floats can handle.

Comment: Thanks heaps! I've been tweaking, and adding my own stuff to this code and it's been great fun! Thanks again :)

Answer (score 0):

Passing as string, but you can change it from file

```
import random

scoresString = '''
James, 0.974

Harry, 0.971

Ben, 0.968

Tom, 0.965

George, 0.964
'''

# How much randoms
randomCount = 2

# Get lines of the pure string
linesPure = scoresString.split("\n")

# Get lines that have content
rowsContent = [line for line in linesPure if(line.strip())]

# Get random lines
chosenRows = random.sample(rowsContent, randomCount)

# Sum of chosen
sum = 0

for crow in chosenRows:
    sum += float(crow.split(",")[1].strip())

# Calculate average
average = sum / len(chosenRows)

print("Average: %0.3f" % average)
```